# Custom HTTP Headers for local dev server when running 'flutter run -d web'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

We would like the local dev server to allow the `X-Frame-Options` header. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible to use custom headers yet.

But the `X-Frame-Options` header was removed in debug mode with this MR:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/62115